# React.js append elements to existing svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to build a chart using [chart-parts](https://github.com/microsoft/chart-parts) library. Since library doesn't provide Grid, I'm trying to build my own using SVG and inject it into an existing component:

```
<Chart id="chart" width={650} height={400} data={data}>
  <LinearScale name="y" domain={[0, 2000]} range="height" zero />
  <BandScale name="x" domain="data.title" range="width" padding={0.5} />
  <Grid/>
  <Axis
    orient="left"
    scale="y"
  />
</Chart>
```

where Grid is my custom svg:

```
const Grid = () => (
 <>
    <defs>
      <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 S 0 0 0 0" fill="none" stroke="gray" strokeWidth="1"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)"/>
  </>
);
```

The problem is that all components inside Chart are rendered as SVGs but my custom one react is trying to render as an html:

> The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

Is there a way I can tell react to append Grid to existing svg? Wrapping grid in a separate svg doesn't work, as I need only 1 svg element.

Comment: You may try to use SVG-friendly [`<g>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) tag to wrap your `<Grid />`contents  instead of dummy tag `<>`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks, just tried it and it didn't work. Says <g> isn't recognisable too

Comment: @Desiigner where is root <svg> rag rendered? in which component?

Comment: @SergiiShvager <Chart> is rendering it

Comment: @Desiigner which version of react are you using?

Comment: @SergiiShvager 16.13

Comment: What about using chart-parts components instead of SVG tags? https://github.com/microsoft/chart-parts/tree/master/packages/client/react/src/marks

Comment: @SergiiShvager they've got poor documentation and I thought that creating my own svg is better than guessing what a particular prop is supposed to mean

Comment: @Desiigner Looks like you can't use pure svg there. They are using virtual svg which is object and then there is special renderer. You can read more here: https://microsoft.github.io/chart-parts/documentation/architecture#architecture-diagram